# code run on tensorflow cpu version, won't run on tensorflow gpu version, trying cnn bilstm model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am currently working on my CQF final on deep learning right now.

I built a cnn-bilstm-attention model earlier as the course progress. When I throw in more and more features into the model, the training process was getting slower and slower. 4 features will drag me down to 10s per epoch. So I re-did my windows, and everything. Set up with newest miniconda3 with python 3.9.16, tensorflow-gpu & keras ==2.10, cuda == 11.5 with cudnn, all worked up with deep learning codes.

The cnn-bilstm-attention script was working on tensorflow==2.15, but slow. When I moved to tensorflow-gpu==2.10, it won't work. Stopped at Epoch 1, nothing showing up, no error, no warning, nothing. GPU memery occupancy drops to normal level after 10 ~ 15 seconds later.

However, autoencoder model does work on both tensorflow, cpu and gpu version without a problem, the training dataset on autoencoder is even tripled than what i have on cnn-bilstm-attention model. It is just this cnn-lstm-attention model won't run on tensorflow-gpu==2.10. I did some research on lstm vs cudnnlstm, and I switched, nothing changed, still stuck on epoch 1.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working? I am not a CS guy, python is the only language I am familiar with. Any hints would be helpful I suppose. Thank you very much.

Comment: You didn't include any code, we cannot help or suggest without details.

Comment: like i said, it wasn't the codes problem, it was the cudnn problem at last. Thanks professor @Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 1):

it seems i found the solution to my problem. finally the epoch 1 is running with reasonable responses.

My machine is using cuda==11.5.2, so only 11.x version of cudnn is working with it. My original cudnn==8.3.2.44, so i upgraded to 8.5.0, 8.7.0, 8.9.0, all the way to the latest 8.9.6.50.

and the latest cudnn==8.9.6.50 for cuda==11.5.2 is working for my cnn-bilstm-attention model python code.

I hope my method provided some problem-fixing hints to those who have also experienced this problem.

=======MACHINE SPECS=======
i9-13900K + RTX4080 + 48G DDR5 RAM

LATEST MINICONDA AS OF 20240101

PYTHON = 3.9.16

tensorflow-gpu == 2.10.1, keras == 2.10.0

cuda == 11.5.2, cudnn == 8.9.6.50

=======SCREENCUTS=======
[image]

[image]